# Read csv; replace values and save on csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv file and I want to modify the first column by removing all "-". 
After that, I want to save the changes in that same first column.

```
import pandas as pd
clean_order = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/(...)/Page_Clean_test.csv', 'w+', delimiter=';', skiprows=0, low_memory=False) 
clean_order.loc[clean_order['web_scraper_order'].fillna('').str.replace('-', ''), 'web_scraper_order']
clean_order.to_csv('C:/Users/(...)/Page_Clean_test.csv', index=False)

Error:  
File "C:\Users\suiso\PycharmProjects\Teste_SA\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2889, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 70, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 97, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1675, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1683, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'web_scraper_order'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/suiso/PycharmProjects/Teste_SA/Clean Data/Dataframe_comments.py", line 21, in <module>
    clean_order.loc[clean_order['web_scraper_order'].fillna('').str.replace('-', ''), 'web_scraper_order']
  File "C:\Users\suiso\PycharmProjects\Teste_SA\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2899, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Users\suiso\PycharmProjects\Teste_SA\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2891, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'web_scraper_order'
```

Comment: Hey, can you please provide a minimal, reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and also state your question?

Answer (score 0):

### Try changing:

```
clean_order.loc[clean_order['web_scraper_order'].fillna('').str.replace('-', ''), 'web_scraper_order']
```

### To:

```
clean_order = clean_order[clean_order.loc['web_scraper_order'].fillna('').str.replace('-', '')]
```

Comment: Nope, give the same KeyError.

Comment: Try adding the .loc to the inner clean_order; if that doesn't work, make sure 'web_scraper_order' is an actual column using clean_order.columns

Comment: Thanks, 
I was calling the column wrong. Like you said, I use clean_order.columns to print the columns of my csv file.

Comment: Yes, but my csv file has a column (web scraper order) that should only have numbers, but there are lines in this column that contain strings. <br/> Error:  raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]"). KeyError: 'None of [Index([\'159361226526203\', \'159361227026346\', \'159361226526217\', \'You keep mixing up xenophobia and racism with a decision, (...)

Comment: Try: pd.to_numeric(clean_order['web scraper order'])

Comment: Sorry, read it wrong. Can you show the full traceback?

Answer (score 0):

you may use

```
clean_order['web_scraper_order']=clean_order['web_scraper_order'].str.replace('-','')
clean_order.to_csv('filename.csv',index=Flase)
```